# Perl getcwd ending forward slashes

Tags: perl, cwd

I am doing a Perl script to attach another variable to the end of the current working directory, but I am having problems with using the module.

1. If I run getcwd from `D:\`, the value returned is

   ```
   D:/ (with forward slash)
   ```

   If I run getcwd from `D:\Temp\`, the value returned is

   ```
   D:/temp (without forward slash)
   ```

   This makes the situation quite tricky because if I simply do:

   ```
   use Cwd;
   $ProjectName = "Project"; # This is a variable supplied by the user
   $directory = getcwd().$ProjectName."\/";
   print $directory."\n";
   ```

   I will end up with either

   ```
   D:/Project (correct)
   ```

   or

   ```
   D:/TempProject (instead of D:/Temp/Project)
   ```

   Is this a feature in `Cwd`? It does not seem to be in the documentation.
2. I have thought up the following code to solve this issue. It takes 3 lines to do it. Can any of you see a more concise way?

   ```
   use Cwd;
   $ProjectName = "Project"; # This is a variable supplied by the user

   $directory = getcwd();
   $directory =~ s/(.+?)([^\\\/])$/$1$2\//g;  # Append "/" if not terminating with forward/back slash
   $directory .= $ProjectName."\/";

   print $directory."\n";
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) instead of making your own path manipulation routines.

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

$ProjectName = "Project";

$cwd = getcwd();
$directory = File::Spec->catdir($cwd, $ProjectName);

print "$directory\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for making we aware of File::Spec. I have to change my entire script to use catdir and catfile. I am sure that it is better in the long term.

Answer (score 4):

The first case is including the trailing slash because "D:" is a volume specifier. It isn't a valid directory name. "D:/" is analogous to the root directory in Unix/Linux.

Quick and dirty solution:

```
$directory .= '/' unless $directory =~ m|/$|;
```

For a robust and portable solution, use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) or [File::Spec::Functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec/Functions.html) if you prefer a non-object-oriented interface:

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);

my $directory = catdir(getcwd(), $ProjectName);
```

Note that `catdir` does *not* include the trailing slash, and that File::Spec builds paths using the directory separator for the host operating system. (e.g. backslashes on Windows).

Comment: I don't mind either way, and I think File::Spec will do fine for me. Thank you.