# cwd and gwtcwd returns a linux style path on windows

Tags: perl, path, getcwd, cwd

If I run this script:

```
use Cwd;
print "$^O\n";
print cwd;
```

The output is:

```
C:\tmp>perl tmp.pl
msys
/c/tmp
```

How can I get windows style path `C:\tmp`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Perl on Windows, how can I ensure I get the path in the correct case following a chdir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995113/using-perl-on-windows-how-can-i-ensure-i-get-the-path-in-the-correct-case-follo)

Comment: @devnull: Not really a duplicate, IMO, even if the answer given to the other question (i.e. `Win32::GetLongPathName()`) might indeed help here too. (OTOH, this _could_ be considered a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922221/perl-getcwd-ending-forward-slashes).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using built-in `perl` of `msys`, and this version of `perl` will definitely give a Linux-style path. If you installed `Active Perl` and use `Active Perl` to launch your script, the path would be Win32-style:

```
$ /bin/perl5_8.exe path.pl
msys
/c/tmp

$ /c/ActivePerl/bin/perl.exe path.pl
MSWin32
c:/tmp
```

You could use alias in your bash profile to redirect `perl` to `ActivePerl`:

```
alias perl /c/ActivePerl/bin/perl.exe
```

Then:

```
$ which perl
perl is /c/ActivePerl/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not really on Windows, or `$^O` would be `MSWin32`. You're inside the MSYS unix emulation environment, so it's no surprise you have unix-style paths. For a version of Perl that runs on Windows natively, use [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) or [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).